# Water leaked from second floor to first (ground) floor. What should I do / be worried about?

Tags: ceiling, water-damage, stucco

When I was trying to fix a leaky faucet in the bathroom (2nd floor), I made a series of mistakes that lead to having some water go underneath the un-tiled section of the bathroom and into the cutout section of the sub-floor where the water pipes come out.

A few hours later, I noticed a water dripping of the 1st floor ceiling.  I put a bin to catch the water and drilled a small hole in the ceiling to drain the water quickly.  The water stopped dripping in about 4 hours since I initially found the drip.

I would roughly estimate that there is a 1 meter distance between where the cutout section of the sub-floor is and the drip on the ceiling.

The amount of water in the bin was about a glass or two.

My ceiling is stucco / popcorn painted in oil based paint.

What should I do / fix / look out for to make sure there is no damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, I would make sure all the leaks are fixed. I would put fans in the bath to circulate air and help dry things out, possibly 1 downstairs where you drilled the hole, if everything drys out without the floor swelling or the wall board coming down or warping in a couple weeks patch the drilled hole and repaint as needed or replace the wall board if it sags. Over the years I have made quite a few repairs like this, if the water was not dripping for a long time and drys quickly I would not be worried about mold.